Sticky bit on directory seems to prevent modification of files in it. Peculiarity of the distro or norm?
Recently I've noted I cannot edit file owned by another account in /tmp as ordinary user account. By trial and error seems it is due to sticky bit on /tmp. But man page of chmod and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit mention only restriction on deletion and renaming of the files for Linux. My distro is Linux Mint. Is such effect on files content modification peculiar to my distro or the norm? If norm, why is it not in man page?
